# Trigger Form Submit from Child with Parent button React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to submit a Form from Child Component through a button placed in Parent. The Parent is a Slide which has a Next Button and I display my Child Component in one page of a Slide.

What I want to do is: When I press next button from Parent I have to go to the next slide and also to submit the Form Child.

code:
Parent Component:

```
import Slider from "react-slick";

class Parent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    
      errors: {}
    }
     next() {
        this.slider.slickNext();
      }
      previous() {
        this.slider.slickPrev();
      }
       
      render() {
        const settings = {
          dots: true,
          infinite: false
        };
    
        return (
    <div>
          <Slider ref={c => (this.slider = c)} {...settings}>
                        <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }} key={1} >
                          
                          <Child /> //this is the Child I want to submit once I press Next Button
                          
                          <Button id="btn" className="btn btn-primary float-right " type="submit" onClick={this.next}> Next</Button> //this is the next button which sould trigger the submit from Child
                        </div>
                        <div key={2} >
                          <Page2/> 
                          <Button className="btn btn-primary float-right " id="btn" onClick={() =>  this.finish()>Finish</Button>
                          <Button id="btn" className="btn btn-primary float-right " onClick={this.previous}> Previous</Button>
                        </div>           
          </Slider>
    </div>
      );
      }
}
```

Child Component:

```
class Child extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            info: '',
            infoID: 0,
            valid:false,
            errors: {}
        }
this.handleValidSubmit = this.handleValidSubmit.bind(this);
this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

handleValidSubmit() {
    if(valid){
        localStorage.setItem("infoID",this.state.infoID);
        this.sendIDToServerAPI(infoID);
       }else {
        localStorage.setItem("infoID",this.state.infoID);
        this.saveNewInfoAPI(info);
      }
    }
 render() {

        return (
            <div }>

                <Container fluid >

                    <Row >
                        <Col  >

                            <AvForm id="avForm" onValidSubmit={this.handleValidSubmit} onInvalidSubmit=}>
                               <Label >Info</Label>
                               <AvField onChange={this.onChange} name="email" placeholder=""Email/>
                              ........
                              .......
                            </AvForm>

                      </Col>

                    </Row>

                </Container>
            </div>
       );
    }

}
```

I tried to minimise the components because they are too large, I hope is clear enough what I try to do. Can anyone please help me with a solution/idea? I tried to Google it but couldn't find anything helpful.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is keep a state(a flag) something like **submit** which will initially be false.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    submit: false
    ....rest of your code
    }
    

  // function to update the submit state
  const setFormSubmit = () => this.setState({submit: true})
}
```

Now you call **setFormSubmit** on next button click
Now you can pass this state(submit) to your child component.
and whenever the submit is true you will trigger the method to submit the form

You can do this by using componentDidUpdate in your child component.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  // if prev submit and current submit prop is unequal and the submit is true
  if ((prevProps.submit !== this.props.submit) && this.props.submit) {
    // Call method to submit form
  }
}
```